# Calculating mean of ride length between users,

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate the mean of ride length between 2 types of users (members and casuals). However, when I run the code I get the following:

```
ride_length_mean <- data_trip_cleaned%>%
group_by(member_casual)%>%
summarise(average_time = mean(ride_length))
```

> Error:
> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type difftime. Defaulting to continuous.
> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (position_stack).

member_casual

average_time

casual  NA mins
member  NA mins

Comment: `dput(your_data_object)` your data, please.

Comment: `mean(as.numeric(ride_length))`  maybe ? Or `mean(ride_length, na.rm = TRUE)` ? Also, your error message looks like it's coming from `ggplot`, but you haven't shown us any `ggplot` code.

Comment: My apologies, still new,
ave_user_time <- ggplot(ride_length_mean)+ geom_col(mapping = aes(x= member_casual, y = average_time, fill = member_casual), show.legend = FALSE)+ labs(title = "Average Travel Time by User", x = "User", y = "Average time")

Comment: OK. (1) Please include your ggplot code in your question (by editing the question); (2) please show us `data_trip_cleaned %>% select(member_casual, ride_length) %>% summary()` (also as part of your question).

Comment: did you try my second suggestion (`mean(ride_length, na.rm = TRUE)`) ?

Comment: Good day, yes, the second suggestion worked and the NA was removed and my ggplot worked as well. Thank you.